# sscanf remove right bracket C

Tags: scanf

I am trying to extract a string within paranthesis `{abcdefg}`

```
sscanf(line,"{%s}", value);
```

Example: `{abcdefg}`
after sscanf I get abcdefg}

How can I remove the right bracket?
I need to get abcdefg

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX (s)scanf, you can use `%[^}]` to extract everything up to a `}`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    const char* line = "{abcdefg}";
    char extract[100];

    sscanf(line, "{%[^}]",  extract);
    puts(extract); //prints abcdefg

    return 0;
}
```